# Executar uma migração específica no SQLite EntityFramework c#

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite

Tenho um banco de dados em SQLite para o armazenamento de algumas informações, inicialmente no projeto não foi adicionado o conceito do Migrations, mas agora é preciso adicionar um novo campo em uma tabela e se torna necessário realizar a primeira migração e migração de adicionar o novo campo.
Atualmente o banco de dados é criado em tempo de execução: `_context.DataBase.EnsureCreated()`.
Gostaria de saber como posso executar as duas migrações sendo que caso o banco de dados já exista não posso executar a primeira migração, somente adicionar ao BD o registro da migration e aí sim aplicar a segunda migration.
Cheguei a utilizar o comando `_context.DataBase.GetPendingMigrations()` mas neste caso me retorna somente as migrações que nao foram aplicadas no banco de dados.
O projeto é feito `.net6-windows7` e a versão do EntityFramework é a 7.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, para o meu problema resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
if (File.Exists(CaminhoBancoSQLite))
{
    var listaPendencias = Database.GetPendingMigrations().ToList();
    string versaoEF= "7.0.14";
    string migracaoID = "20230000000000_InitialCreate";

    if (listaPendencias .Contains(migracaoID))
    {
        FormattableString criarTabelaSql = $"CREATE TABLE \"__EFMigrationsHistory\" (\r\n\t\"MigrationId\"\tTEXT NOT NULL,\r\n\t\"ProductVersion\"\tTEXT NOT NULL,\r\n\tCONSTRAINT \"PK___EFMigrationsHistory\" PRIMARY KEY(\"MigrationId\")\r\n);";
        Database.ExecuteSql(criarTabelaSql);

        FormattableString inserirMigracaoSql= FormattableStringFactory.Create($"INSERT INTO \"main\".\"__EFMigrationsHistory\" (\"MigrationId\", \"ProductVersion\") VALUES ('{migracaoID}', '{versaoEF}');");
        Database.ExecuteSql(inserirMigracaoSql);
    }
}

Database.Migrate();
```

Com isso eu garanto que a primeira migration será executada caso não tenha sido  atualizado ainda e após eu executo a migração para atualizar com as últimas informações.
E caso não exista ainda o banco de dados, então é executado diretamente o `Migrate()` para criar e atualizar o banco.

Fonte:
[Pending Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.getpendingmigrations?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-relationaldatabasefacadeextensions-getpendingmigrations(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-infrastructure-databasefacade)) - [FormattableStringFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.formattablestringfactory?view=net-6.0)